# Menu item is hiding behind iframe when iframe contains PDF

Tags: iframe

I am using iframe to display pdf(asp.net mvc3).While PDF is in the iframe menu item is not visible ,means it is hiding behind the iframe.
Can anyone let me know how to aolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very bare-bones, please elaborate.

However, here is a solution:

Use z-index in CSS.

Give the iFrame an ID, like so:

```
<iframe id="pdf-display"></iframe>
```

Also give the menu item an ID in a similar fashion, for example `id="menu-item"`. If you have multiple other menu items, contain them in a `<div>` and give the div an ID.

Then, in a separate stylesheet or in `<style>` tags, enter this code:

```
iframe#pdf-display {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}

#menu-item {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

By increase the z-index by one for the menu item, it places the element "above" the iFrame, so to speak. The higher the z-index, the closer to the 'front' the element is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the valid solution to all iframe issues where parent frame content is hiding behind child iframe content is to use absolute positioning on the element you want to show above the iframe.

You can use relative positioned parent element with absolute position child elements for menus, popovers and what ever you wish. This is a catch all solution for any type of iframe or window elements.